# Django StreamHandler log not working in mod_wsgi setup

Tags: django, logging, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get all log messages to go to the standard apache error log, and I just can't get it working. If I write to a file it's fine, but the apache logs flat out don't work. Any advice? Here's my relevant config:

**settings.py (snippet)**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
           '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
   'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'development': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '':{
            'handlers': ['development'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['development'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

---

**virtual host config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv DJANGO_DEBUG True

    ServerName virtualimpact.userhome.test-env.net

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog   "/home/developer/logs/developer-machine_error.log"
    CustomLog "/home/developer/logs/developer-machine_com_access.log" combined

    Alias /static/ /home/developer/htdocs/path/to/htdocs/static/

    <Directory /home/developer/htdocs/path/to/htdocs/static>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/developer/htdocs/path/to/mod_wsgi/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**django.wsgi**

```
import os, sys, site

workspace = os.path.abspath('%s/..' % os.path.dirname(__file__))
activate_this = os.path.abspath('%s/virtpy/bin/activate_this.py' % workspace)
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

sys.path.append(workspace)
sys.path.append('%s/htdocs' % workspace)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'htdocs.settings'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '%s/mod_wsgi/egg-cache' % workspace

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
_application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

def application(environ, start_response):
    os.environ['DJANGO_DEBUG'] = environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', 'False')
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

---

**views.py (snippet)**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('')
...

class AbstractsListView(BaseListView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # none of the below calls write to the error log
        logger.debug('debug it')
        logger.info('info it')
        import sys
        sys.stderr.write('asdfasdf')
        ...
```

If you need any more information please let me know, this thing has been bugging me for a while and I'm at wits end about it.

Thanks in advance.

edit: also, I'm using Python 2.6.6 and Django==1.4.3

### edit: it's logging, but to the wrong file!

So I don't know why I didn't check before, but it turns out anything I write to stdout (or stderr) is going to the logs in /var/log/httpd/, and not the logs I've configured specifically for this VirtualHost. I'm wondering if this is more of a mod_wsgi question than Django, but I can't be sure. Are my mod_wsgi and vhost.conf file correct?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems like this stems from the fact I'm running mod_wsgi under embedded mode and not as a daemon. Soon as I switched it over, my logs started to appear in the correct place. We'll see how it fares, but so far so good.